# How high can I go?

Tags: astroneer

Let's say I have infinite energy and oxigen. If I start raising the terrain right below my feet, where would I end?

Possible answers I'm considering:

- Limit of **x** km height.
- You start flying because of low gravity force.
- You land on another planet (this would be too weird).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, answering my own question, if you start building terrain below your feet, you'd get to a certain point where there's no possibility to keep creating terrain upwards so, basically, there's a limit.